# VSCode source.organizeImports ignore specific file

Tags: angular, typescript, visual-studio-code, import, config

I have a problem which I'm not sure how to deal that. I have some unused imports in one of my angular components. My VSCode config source.organizeImports set to true so it always deletes unused imports, maybe there is a way how can I exclude some files from deleting unused imports. I read similar issue, but with excluding files from sorting them. Solution was to implement eslint property "source.fixAll.eslint": true and adding comment next to import /* eslint-disable import/order */. I tried to find similar functionality in eslint for unused imports, but didn't find anything. I also read that you can use prettier and install https://github.com/simonhaenisch/prettier-plugin-organize-imports this npm to override VSCode config, but problem that in my current project I have to use only legit npm packages. Things like disabling specific programming language in configs also not solution. If someone have some ideas or faced similar problem please give me your solution, Thanks.